# Can't create inner class in APEX?

Tags: apex, execute-anonymous

Consider the following code:

```
public class OuterClass {
    public class InnerClass { // error!
    }
}

new OuterClass();
```

Why does it cause this error:

> unexpected token: 'class'

The documentation says this is how it's done. Example code says this is how it's done. The JSON2APEX generator is outputting code like this. Whey does the compiler throw errors then?

Comment: are you doing this in anonymous apex?

Comment: Yes, in the Execute Anonymous of the IDE.

Comment: if I remember right, you can't do this in execute anonymous; you have to use DC and create a real class that gets saved to your org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working just fine. In Anonymous apex you can only call Code snippet or existing accessible static methods or instance method.

In order to execute above code, you will need to save Class definition in apex class named "OuterClass".

```
public class OuterClass {
    public class InnerClass {  
         //Your code here
    }
}
```

and then use below code in anonymous apex :

```
new OuterClass();
```

Comment: Ah. Can't say I'm not annoyed. Wish there was a good "scratch-pad" for APEX the way I can use LINQPad for C# without having to actually publish stuff up to the org, then deal with tests because all of the sudden it's under the limit and you know it's prototype code that's going to change a zillion times before it's final. Sigh, oh, well. Thanks for the help, I'll start publishing now then.